# ASP.NET: Response.BinaryWrite inside UpdatePanel inside Child User Control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, parent-child, binarywriter

So I have the following scenario:

--- Page.aspx ---

```
UpdatePanel
   ListView
      UserControl.ascx
```

--- UserControl.ascx ---

```
    ListView
        Button|ID:btnDownloadAttachment
```

I use the following method to downlaod attachment:

```
public void OpenDocument(byte[] AttContent, string fileName, string inExtension)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + inExtension);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", AttContent.Length.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(AttContent);
}
```

But since the content is inside an update panel I get the following error:

"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed."

Comment: You cannot download a file over AJAX.

Comment: @SLaks I need the Update Panel there is there anyway I can get around this?

Comment: No.  You need a postback.

Answer (score 5):

If you run fiddler to see the response, I'm guessing you'll see your download.  The problem is the partial page rendering.  When the client side gets it thinks it should be getting a page update and instead gets a binary file.  There's a couple of solutions:

Option #1, disable partial page rendering entirely for the page (must be done in page_init):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ScriptManager mgr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
  mgr.EnablePartialRendering = false;
}
```

Option #2 force a postback with the control initiating the download:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(BtnExport);
```

Option #3 create a postback trigger

```
<asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <triggers>
        <asp:postbacktrigger ControlID="BtnExport"/>
    </triggers>
</asp:updatepanel>
```